# What is the logic behind these functions

Tags: dart

I am learning Dart, and I can't understand the logic behind this code if anyone can help:

```dart
Function applyMultiplier(num multiplier) {
  return (num value) {
    return value * multiplier;
  };
}

final triple = applyMultiplier(3);
print(triple(6)); //output 18
```

1. There is an anonymous function inside a named function.
2. We assigned a function to a variable.

What I don't understand is how did we pass from **triple** to **value**. I can't understand the logic behind.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the function applyMultiplier takes a num as argument and returns a function that itself returns the value it is given multiplied by another multiplier. `final tripple = applyMultiplier(3)` stores this function that is returned from applyMultiplier in the variable triple. Because the variable triple then stores a function it can also be used like a function.

Comment: num actually is the type of the argument. That's what made me confused because **applyMultiplier** has **multiplier** as an argument while **return** has **value** as an argument.

Comment: @bahazou `multiplier` and `value` are the names of two separate arguments. `multiplier` is the argument to the `applyMultiplier` function. `value` is the argument to the `Function` object that `applyMultiplier` returns.